# Where is a file type info in Excel file structure?

Tags: excel, email, abap, email-attachments

In our SAP ABAP-based application we have a mail sending functionality. The problem is, it's an old framework and it takes only 3 characters file types for attachments. We now want to send `.xlsx` files. But the framework only takes first 3 characters so it works with `.xls`. So when a user opens an attachment he gets the following message:

> The file you are trying to open, 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.XLS', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?
>
> [image]

Now, I know one solution is to go to Trust center and hide that kind of messages. The another framework that generates the `.xlsx` files can only generate `.xlsx`. But I can enhance it.

My question is: in the Excel file structure (when extracted via 7zip), is there somewhere an information about what kind of file (filetype) in the file I just extracted?

Because if the message in the Excel is shown, I can imagine that there is a check that checks filetype of a file and some information in `xml` files in the Excel file structure.

Thanks.

Comment: "I can imagine that there is a check that checks filetype of a file and some information ... in the excel file structure." Yes there is. But a `*.xls` file normally does not contains any XML but is a binary file in `BIFF` format. Only `*.xlsx` files are ZIP files containing XML files. So the Excel check does the following: If a file comes as `*.xls` but is not a binary file in `BIFF` format, then do warning.

Comment: Yep, Alex is right, old `xls` is binary, whist `xlsx` is xml. I assume you cannot omit this warning as you cannot modify binary.

Comment: Just change the framework. What tool do you use for sending?

Comment: You are saying that your SAP system is "an old framework and it takes only 3 characters file types for attachments" so it looks like you have created an ABAP program without looking at the [SAP note 1459896 - BCS: Support for four-digit file name extensions](https://me.sap.com/notes/1459896) for adding the email attachment. Note that Excel requires that if you open a file with the `.xlsx` extension, your [Excel file should also be containing data formatted according to Office Open XML for Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats), otherwise you'll get an Excel warning.